# Python basic result format

Tags: python

```
def meter_to_cm(m):
    cm = m * 10
    print(m,'m equals to',cm,'cm')

meter_to_cm(12)
```

The result shows

```
(12, 'm equals to', 120, 'cm')
```

How can I make it do not show the parentheses, quotes and commas?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: 12m is equal to 1200cm by the way.

Comment: Very helpful: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: It's python 3.5.2 and i type it in Pycharm Community Edition 2016.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python 3, use following

```
def meter_to_cm(m):
    cm = m * 100
    print("{0} m equals to {1} cm".format(m, cm))

meter_to_cm(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 the print statement isn't a function. If you run

```
print(m, 'm equals to', cm, 'cm')
```

that would actually be equal to

```
print (m, 'm equals to', cm, 'cm')
```

which prints a tuple (hence the parentheses in the output).

So my guess would be that your project uses Python 2 instead of Python 3. In PyCharm you should check the run configuration or the project SDK (File > Project Structure > Project).

If you actually use Python 2

```
print m, 'm equals to', cm, 'cm'
```

should print the text without parentheses.